# How to send response in mid of multiple async calls to database in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

Need to terminate `POST` function and send `Error: something` as response, without terminating program.

Sample `for-loop`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < req.body.listoftouristsbyid.length; i++) {
  client.query("SELECT tourists.id FROM tourists WHERE tourists.id = " + req.body.listoftouristsbyid[i], function(err, result) {
    done();
    if (result.rows.length === 0) {
      console.log("Tourist " + req.body.listoftouristsbyid[i] + " you want to add does not exist");
      res.status(500);
      return res.render("Bad listoftoutistbyid request, student with id " + i + " does not exist");
    }
  })
}
```

What should I write in place of `return res.render`, so POST won't work, function will terminate with error code in response, but without crashing program so I can send more requests later ?

Comment: Instead of making a lot of requests to DB I would just make one query by combining them with `OR` ...

Comment: And I hope you do input validation.

Comment: You could use `try ... catch` statement.

Comment: @rahul nope, he can't

Comment: @Jonas Wilms "And I hope you do input validation" What does that mean?

Comment: That means that any visitor of your website might have fun with your db https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: What do you mean by "without crashing program" ? You are setting yourself a 500 error code. Maybe you want to set a 404 instead ?

Comment: TGrif Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client  Thats what i got in terminal. Only thing i get in Postman response is custom "Could not get any response, there was error in..." but my error message is completely ignored. Command i try now is res.status(404).send({status:404, message: 'internal error', type:'internal'});  i dont know why its not working as it should

Comment: The error is very clear, `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.  You can send response only once.  Second iteration of your for loop is trying to send response, that's where it is crashing.

Comment: Well don't do a lot of queries in a loop and try to send a response after each of them returns. There can only be one response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `async-await` for this, as it's highly used among asynchronous call handlers like `Promise` and `Generators`.

Here's a sample code:

```
app.post('/APIendpoint', async (req, res) => {

    let listoftouristsbyid      = req.body.listoftouristsbyid;

    let dbResult = [];

    // Can put this whole for loop inside try too. Then success response will also be inside try after for-loop
    for (let i = 0; i < listoftouristsbyid.length; i++) {

        try {
            let result = await callDB( "SELECT tourists.id FROM tourists WHERE tourists.id = " + listoftouristsbyid[i] );
            dbResult.push(result);
        }
        catch (err) {

            console.log("Tourist " + listoftouristsbyid[i] + " you want to add does not exist");

            res.status(500);
            return res.send("Bad listoftoutistbyid request, student with id " + i + " does not exist");

        }
    }

    console.log("Successfully fetched all records ", dbResult);

    res.status(200);
    return res.send(dbResult);

});

function callDB(query) {

    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
        client.query(query, function(err, result) {

            if (result.rows.length === 0) {
                reject("not found");
            } else {
                resolve(result.rows);
            }

        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [async.map](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) to solve your problem.  `for` loop is not gonna work with async functions.

```
async.map(
    req.body.listoftouristsbyid, 
    function(touristId, callback) {
        client.query("<query>", function(err, result) {
            if (result.rows.length === 0) {
                callback(new Error("not found"));
            }
            callback(null, result);
        });
    },
    function(err, result) {
        // send response here.
    } 
);
```